# MongoDB $not operator performance

Tags: performance, mongodb

How does $not operator influences on query performance?

So we have 2 queries:

```
{condition}
```

and

```
{$not: {condition}}
```

Will their performances be quite similar or not?

Comment: run an explain() for both type of queries and see the output for yourself

Comment: Only for this query. The problem is, that the operator may have differen performance impact on different indexies (or without them).

Comment: Without index both queries perform like same. The difference comes with the usage of index. With index $not query has to examine all the keys first. Then it return the documents matched. While for the {condition} type queries it just need to examine the particular key

Comment: Nothing will tell you for sure other than real life benchmarking.